# Django | twilio to send SMS

Tags: django, twilio

I'm using twilio as for a mobile verification mechanism,  I have no prior experience in using twilio but looking at the sample PHP code I used this one in my code but apparently it's giving me an `400 Bad request` HTTP error. Here's the code:

```
    d = {
        'TO' : '*** *** ****',
        'FROM' : '415-555-1212',
        'BODY' : 'Hello user, please verify your device using                    this code %s' % verNumber
    }
    try:
        print account.request('/%s/Accounts/%s/SMS/Messages' % \
                            (API_VERSION, ACCOUNT_SID), 'POST', d)
    except Exception, e:
        return HttpResponse('Error %s' % e)
```

`verNumber` is randomly generated and the receiver's  number is validated in twilio.

I follow the exception and found this error

```
Error 400 The source 'From' phone number is required to send an SMS
```

What does this mean.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [some of the twilio examples](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/) from the python libraries I notice that the dictionaries containing the payload are typed in MixedCase whereas you've used UPPERCASE.

The error might be quite straight forward rather than

```
d = {
    'TO' : '*** *** ****',
    'FROM' : '415-555-1212',
    'BODY' : 'Hello user, please verify your device using this code %s' % verNumber
}
```

try

```
d = {
    'To' : '*** *** ****',
    'From' : '415-555-1212',
    'Body' : 'Hello user, please verify your device using this code %s' % verNumber
}
```

The SMS Quickstart ( in the documentation) supports this idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice catch Jamie! Can I send you a tshirt from Twilio? If so, email me your address and shirt size to jsheehan at twilio dot com

Comment: +John, can I get a Twilio t-shirt?! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://bitbucket.org/vgavro/django-smsgate/ , you may need to write backend for twilio - but the rest is done for you already.